# Ruby Workflow - Bundle Install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, bundle-install

Where does bundle install fit into the add-commit-push workflow?  In other words, when is it necessary.

Comment: `bundler` and `git` don't depend on each other, they are unrelated and fulfill two different responsibilities. You might use both in the same project but you can use `bundler` without `git` and `git` without `bundler`. Therefore your question is unclear to me.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to launch `bundle install` every time that you update your `Gemfile`.

Before you run it, make sure you have `bundler` gem installed:

```
$ gem install bundler
```

You can integrate this command and several others adding some [git hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks). For example, I use [`overcommit` gem](https://github.com/brigade/overcommit) to make sure that some actions are performed before commit, merge and push.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to ensure that you have run `bundle install` before adding files to a git commit.
You should be in the habit of running `bundle install` every time your `Gemfile` is changed.

***Please note:*** Git and Bundler are *independent*. The only reason you want to have run `bundle install` before adding to git is to ensure that your `Gemfile.lock` is updated to contain the latest information.